# Function Pointers in C++/CX

Tags: c++-cx

**Background**

I'm writing a Windows Store App in C++ using the Windows Store Unit Test Project. While trying to figure out how to test that an exception was raised, I found  Assert::ExpectedException in CppUnitTestAssert.h. Its signatures are below:

```
template<typename _EXPECTEDEXCEPTION, typename _RETURNTYPE> static void ExpectException(_RETURNTYPE (*func)(), const wchar_t* message = NULL, const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
template<typename _EXPECTEDEXCEPTION, typename _FUNCTOR> static void ExpectException(_FUNCTOR functor, const wchar_t* message = NULL, const __LineInfo* pLineInfo = NULL)` 
{
    ...
}
```

**The Question Is:**

It's been a LONG time since I coded in C++, so I'm having difficulty figuring out how to call the method correctly. I keep getting the following error:

```
'Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::ExpectException' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I realize this may be actually be a misunderstanding of "pure" C++, but I'm not sure if C++/CX may have different rules for using function pointers that C++. Or at least what I remember the rules to be.

EDIT:

I'm attempting to use the function pointer overload, _RETURNTYPE (*func)(), not the __FUNCTOR overload. Here is the code that is failing to compile.

```
Assert::ExpectException<InvalidArgumentException, int>(&TestClass::TestMethod);
```

Here is TestMethod:

```
void TestMethod()
{
}
```

Comment: ...What are you trying to pass as a _FUNCTOR?

Comment: Yeah, that would probably have helped, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think you might be better off trying the _FUNCTOR version. It seems to me that the first overload would match a global function, not a member function as you're trying to use... or just try using a global function to test).

Comment: I could certainly try that.

Answer (score 0):

The second type in the `ExpectException` template (`_RETURNTYPE` in the declaration), needs to match the return type of the function passed into it. You've used `int` but your function returns `void`, so this gives a compiler error. If you want to be explicit here the second type should be `void`. However, as the compiler can figure out the type from the function parameter you don't need to specify it. Try this:

```
Assert::ExpectException<InvalidArgumentException>(TestClass::TestMethod);
```