# How to call the Assert::ExpectException correctly?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, assertion, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I'm writing some unit tests using Microsoft's CppUnitTestFramework.

I want to test, if the method I call throws the correct exception. My code is:

```
TEST_METHOD(test_for_correct_exception_by_input_with_whitespaces)
{
            std::string input{ "meet me at the corner" };
            Assert::ExpectException<std::invalid_argument>(AutokeyCipher::encrypt(input, primer));              
}
```

In the link below I wrote the call similar to the last answer:

[Function Pointers in C++/CX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520493/function-pointers-in-c-cx)

When compiling it, I get the **C2064** Error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Why isn't that working?

Comment: _"Why isn't that working?"_ How exactly isn't it working?

Comment: Oh Sry, you are Right, forgot to write that information to the post. Wait, I’ll edit it!

Comment: really no one who can help?

Comment: Just be patient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the code under test in a lambda expression to be called by the `Assert::ExpectException` function.

```
void Foo()
{
    throw std::invalid_argument("test");
}

TEST_METHOD(Foo_ThrowsException)
{
    auto func = [] { Foo(); };
    Assert::ExpectException<std::invalid_argument>(func);
}
```

Comment: This works because the lambda is non-capturing, and therefore can be converted to a `void(*)(void)` function pointer. `Assert::ExpectException` needs a function pointer.

Comment: @MSalters: That is not true. At least at the time of this comment, there is an overload which takes any parameterless functor

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
Assert::ExpectException<std::invalid_argument>([]() {
    foo();
    });
```