# Advise on microsoft visual C++ unit test feature ExpectException

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, functor

I have a class with a method called *func* and it takes a bool argument and returns void.

```
class Test {
public:
    void func (bool b);
}
```

To test it, I use VS UnitTest framework and would like to test with Assert::ExpectException.
It needs a FUNCTOR type as its argument. How should I decorate the **func** method - as a lambda function or operator () in another class- to be tested?

Comment: [How to call the Assert::ExpectException correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54268091/how-to-call-the-assertexpectexception-correctly) may help you use the overload that accepts a function pointer.